# swapping values in react/redux - only works once

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am building a two player game in react/redux. There is always one player whose turn it is. The turn needs to change regularly between the two.

I have the following reducer. It works once, and then stops working.

```
   case CHANGE_TURN:
      if (playerTurn === 1) {
        newPlayerTurn = 2;
        newOtherPlayer = 1;
      }
      else {
        newPlayerTurn = 1;
        newOtherPlayer = 2;
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        otherPlayerID: newOtherPlayer,
        playerTurnID: newPlayerTurn
      }
```

Since this part has worked in the past, I think perhaps something else is getting in the way????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloned your repo and checked it out. 
Your `players.js` reducer, line 5 is:

```
let playerTurn = players.playerTurnID;
```

But should look like:

```
let playerTurn = state.playerTurnID;
```

You should get your `playerTurn` from your `state` object.

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer was accepted but you can also minimize your swapping operation by using:

```
[newPlayerTurn, newOtherPlayer] = [newOtherPlayer, newPlayerTurn];
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have forgotten to alternate `playerTurn` between `1` and `2` by returning it in the state. Also, the case can be simplified:

```
case CHANGE_TURN:
    return {
        ...state,
        playerTurn: state.playerTurn === 1 ? 2 : 1,
        otherPlayerID: state.playerTurn === 1 ? 1 : 2,
        playerTurnID: state.playerTurn === 1 ? 2 : 1,
    };
```

`playerTurn` and `playerTurnID` are redundant btw, but maybe your example was simplified.

If it's strictly always exactly two players, one boolean is enough to model the entire state:

```
case CHANGE_TURN:
    return { activePlayer: !state.activePlayer };
```

With an `initialState` of `{ activePlayer: false }`. You could then write selectors like

```
const isPlayer1Active = (state) => !state.activePlayer; // false = player1's turn
const isPlayer2Active = (state) => state.activePlayer; // true = player2's turn
const getActivePlayerID = (state) => state.activePlayer ? 2 : 1;
```